# Обращение к разным полигонам объекта Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: Объект с 2 и более материалами]

Необходимо изменять материалы на различных поверхностях объекта через скрипт. Когда тело нуждается всего в одном материале, нет проблемы просто обращаться через sharedMaterial, но как менять материалы на разных полигонах одного объекта (когда после экспорта fbx меш предполагает несколько материалов)

```
public Material[] material;
Renderer rend;


void Start()
{
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rend.enabled = true;
    rend.sharedMaterial = material[0];

}
void Update()
{
    
   
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rend.sharedMaterial = material[1];
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        rend.sharedMaterial = material[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Переписывать структуру самого меша дробя на `subMesh`, по сути создавать еще одинновый меш. Процедура затратная в всех аспектах.

Comment: Как я понял, лучше отказаться от этой механики?

Comment: Можно натянуть в 3d редакторе несколько материалов на меш, так будет массив материалов, но затратно по рендеру на 1 меш много материалов